# How to Extract Multiple "View State" (almost 50) from the Response effectively and in a simple way other than using the regular expression extractor

Tags: apache, performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

How to Extract Multiple "View State" (almost 50) from the Response effectively and in a simple way other than using the regular expression extractor

Step:

1. I basically have a page which contains almost 50 "viewstate" which needs to be fed to the next request, to process.Is there any method by which i can extract this effectively other than using 50 variables in regular expression extractor.

Any help would be really appreciable.

[image]

Can we regular expression extractor by setting "Match No" as "-1" and use same variable name set in the reg expression extractor and use it in sampler?
Also could anyone please tell how to set the variable name too ?

Comment: you have shared the image of http request sampler where you are using view states, could you please post response from which you have to extract the view states value?

Answer (score 1):

My expectation is that VIEWSTATE is a [hidden input](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_hidden.asp) so you can automate handling of this VIEWSTATE parameters like:

1. Add [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter) to fetch hidden inputs names like:

   [image]
2. Add another CSS Selector Extractor to fetch hidden inputs values like:

   [image]
3. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the next request and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   1.upto(vars.get('hiddenInputName_matchNr') as int, { index ->
       def hiddenInputName = vars.get('hiddenInputName_' + index)
       if (hiddenInputName.startsWith('__VIEWSTATE')) {
           sampler.addArgument(hiddenInputName, vars.get('hiddenInputValue_' + index))
       }
   })
   ```

   [image]
4. That's it, the JSR223 PreProcessor should add all the VIEWSTATE parameters to the request in the runtime.

Comment: So What about the value that needs to be given in the next sampler where the JSR223 PreProcessor is been added as child.

Comment: If you have to pass only VIEWSTATE - then nothing, if anything else - then only those parameters except the VIEWSTATE

Comment: I have given as you have mentioned, but unfortunately its not working.Screenshots are attached below.

Comment: 1. Check if you have `hiddenInputName_` and `hiddenInputValue_` variables defined using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)
2. Check if there are no suspicious entries in [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging) file
3. Your `__EVENTVALIDATION`, `__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR`, `__EVENTTARGET`, etc. parameters also require [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start)

Comment: is there anyway through the regular expression extractor for handling multiple variable by putting 
Match No as "-1" and
Name of the created variable "VIEWSTATE_1,VIEWSTATE_2"